# Как сделать так, чтоб при нажатии на CHECK BOX значение из колонки В копировалось в С и обратно

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Значений в колонке B может быть много. Но копироваться в колонку с должно только в той строке где стоит чекбокс. Есть небольшой набросок но скрип исполняется бесконечно и не может остановится. Может кто знает как сделать проверку пустая ли ячейка ?

```
function onEdit(e) {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
var cell2 = sheet1.getRange('H11');       
var x= cell2.getValue();

if(x == true) 
 {
spreadsheet.getRange('E11').activate();
spreadsheet.getRange('D11').moveTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange());
}

else if(x == false)
{ 
spreadsheet.getRange('D11').activate();
spreadsheet.getRange('E11').moveTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange());    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо именно копирование?

Присваивание ячейке "C" ссылки на значение ячейки "B" не подойдёт?

[image: Пример]

Comment: не получится. как копирование будет происходить в ячейку С? а если отметить D то должно произойти обратное копирование/перемещение